# how to do division in sub total in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I developed a SSRS report. The output is as below

[image]

Here i have subtotal for amt, cust and Tbl. I need subtotal for Avg also.

[image]

I tried below formulas in the subtotal columns

```
=[Sum(total)]/[Sum(cust_count)]
```

and the output is as below

[image]

How can i achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this expression:

```
=Sum(Fields!amt.Value) / Sum(Fields!cust.Value)
```

Assuming that:

- `Sum(Fields!amt.Value)` is the expression used to obtain `183.00` in you example
- `Sum(Fields!cust.Value)` is the expression used to obtain `8.00` in you example